# 2 Questions concerning Javascript Image-Object

Tags: javascript, image, object, onload

1. When i create an image-object using .createElement('img'), but i dont use it in the document.body, do i have to remove it after i have created it? I only need the image-object to read the size of an image. I know, when using new Image(), the garbage-collector will delete the object. But what about .createElement('img')?
2. Do i have to use the img.onload Event, also if i put base64 coded images to the src-attribute of the image? -> img.src = base64-string. I do not use a Imgage-URL to make a Request to the Server!

Answer (score 0):

The GC *should* collect the image, but not if any closures depend on that variable. So make sure you use `var` correctly.

You can't get the size of the image reliably unless you use the `onload` event to make sure it's loaded. However with `data:` URLs it should be instantaneous, so you can probably get the dimensions straight away.

Comment: thanx for quick answer, i tried loading that image without onload event, and it failed. For base64.onload it worked!?!o_O Dont know...anyhow thanx alot